# Nested modal view controller gives strange message under iOS6?

Tags: ios6, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am presenting a modal view controller from another modal view controller, and this worked fine under all iOS versions prior to iOS6. But under iOS6 I am getting the following warning message in the emulator:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x14e93680> on <UINavigationController: 0x9fc6b70> while a presentation is in progress!
```

The modal view controller is not shown if this warning appears. Basically I am using code like this to show the modal view controller:

```
WebAuthViewController *authController = [[WebAuthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
authController.challenge = challenge;
authController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authController];
[self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
[aNavController release];
[authController release];
```

The view that is already shown is a UIWebView also shown in a modal view, like this:

```
WebViewController *addController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
addController.urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
addController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

[navigationController release];
[addController release];
```

The apple docs still suggest that one is supposed to be able to stack navigation controllers like this, so I am at a loss to explain why this happens. Any hints?

Comment: May I ask why did you unaccept? Is my answer incorrect or is there a better answer?

Comment: Accidentally, thick fingers on my iPhone. Did not want to touch the tick mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view controller can only present a single view controller. This might have been allowed before, but is probably enforced in iOS6 due to an internal reorganization (`presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated in iOS6). It's time to change your organization of view controllers. Perhaps it is possible to introduce a navigation controller which is to be presented. If there is already a presented view controller, push your next one to the navigation stack.

Comment: OK, I did miss that one due to the web view controller being used from multiple situations, only one being in a modal already. I am now using only one modal dialog level and just push the authentication instead of doing yet another level of modal dialog there, works fine

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was really dumb - I forgot the quotes around the URL for curl and the shell did execute the command in the background without arguments.